# get google maps link using gwt maps api

Tags: google-maps, gwt

How do you get the link to google maps image so i can attached to a email and send.  Using the google web toolkit api.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Static Maps API to build a URL to get the image you need.

Google Static Maps
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Comment: @Eric, your edit could have been a stand-alone answer on its own, it adds _significantly_ to @Perishable's answer..